# Why are manual chunks empty in Vue with Vite + Rollup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading, vite, rollup

In my Vue + Vite + Rollup project I am trying to create several chunks from json files.

I have multiples json files like `default.json`, `extensions.json` and `alternatives.json` in my `/src/data/` folder and I want `alternatives.json` (and potentially others) to be in a separate chunk in order to load it asynchronously with

```
function loadData(filename) {
  ...  
  return () => import(`./data/${filename}.json`)
}
```

when it is needed.

Based on an example from the [Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#with-vite) I thought I can use the `rollup.output.manualChunks` and therefore set the following option in my  `vite.config.js`

```
...
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {
          'group-data': [
            './src/data/alternatives.json',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

With `npm run build` a separate chunk `group-data.(...).js` is generated in `/dist/`,  but the file is empty.

**Question**

What could be the reason for the chunk file being empty, or did I choose a wrong approach for asynchonously loading json files via chunks and dynamic imports?

Comment: I usually put data like that in the `/public/data` folder - it gets deployed into `/data` just as if it were in `/src/data` but isn't processed at all bye the build process

Comment: I was thinking about this option as well, but I need some of the json files inside ```/src/``` since I need them in the "main chunk" and I also like to have files that belong together in one place.

Comment: But if some files are bundled and others aren't, do they really belong together 

Comment: ok, I couldn't get the specific separate chunk that I wanted, so I've decided to separate _all_ the chunks  https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-preservemodules

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **you are not exporting anything from your manual chunks**, pay attention to the fact that even though you export something but not import it in your app, your manual chunks **will still be empty**.

**My solution:**

I added an exported empty function in my manual chunks and imported it in one of my application modules, for simplicity and clarity I imported it in the **app.tsx** file, next, in order to make your import working, you need to call the function. **Example**:

In your manual chunk (in my case called content.ts):
[manual chunk file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho8BI.png)

In your app.tsx:
[app.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BHYO.png)